# Video or animation for continuity equation in water pipes

Tags: specific-reference, education, fluid-dynamics

I am looking for an animation or even better a video with a real experiment, which shows that at constant flow rate the speed of water in a pipe is higher at narrower parts of a pipe.

[image: Water flow from Halliday]

I googled for hours but didn't find any material. So if someone knows good animations or videos for this, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://youtu.be/DOUfyDHxkYQ?t=4m53s (the relevant visualisation starts at around 4:53, but if you watch from the beginning it shows you how the experiment is set up and demonstrates other things such as stream lines), or http://youtu.be/LI9Mi1KhFTs?t=3m4s

They're from a series of films made in the '60s by the "National Committee for Fluid Mechanics Films", which are a rather nice resource in general for videos of fluid dynamics demonstrations.  [This page](http://web.mit.edu/hml/ncfmf.html) has them all in RealPlayer format - I usually get the title from that page and then search for it on YouTube, since it's more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

I dunno about a video, but you can certainly show this at home:

- Blow water through a hose with a nozzle
- Show how faucet water decreases in radius as it falls (since it becomes faster)
- Cinch half the opening of a straw
- Fill a funnel, while keeping the neck blocked. Now, unblock it, and see how water comes out pretty fast but the water level inside decreases slowly.
- (*Credit @MikeDunlavey*) Not a water example, but notice how traffic slows down at bottlenecks and speeds up th moment you exit one.

Comment: + Also, the next time you're stuck in traffic because the road is narrow ahead, notice how you move slowly until you get to the narrow place, and then you move fast.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey True. Though in that case, stress/pressure increases in the bottleneck :P

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found this short animation:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=endscreen&v=k8IRxT1sM6s